# Show different UI elements using Angularjs 1.7.x ng-repeat (key, val) in nested array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm very new to angularjs and I am trying to figure out ng-repeat with key/value pair. I have attached the following image with the expected result. Here's the code I'm trying but the result I am getting is not accurate.[image: ng-repeat result]

Here's my html code

```
.row(ng-repeat="(key, prop) in stars")
   div(ng-repeat="val in prop")
     i.star.yellow.icon
```

And here's my angular scope

```
$scope.stars = {
    count: {
      one: ['1'],
      two: ['1','2'],
      three: ['1','2','3']
    }
};
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring the fact that your `prop` on your first `ng-repeat` is `count`. So your second `ng-repeat` isn't looking at your array but rather the number of objects in `count`

Comment: So do I have to change my array structure?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by changing the array structure in controller and did not use key/prop

```
// Controller - Array structure
$scope.rows = [{
   one: '',
   stars: ['1','2','3']
}, {
   two: '',
   stars: ['1','2']
}, {
   three: '',
   stars: ['1']
}];

// ng-repeat on UI
.row(ng-repeat="row in rows")
  .one.wide.middle.right.floated.right.aligned.column
      .row(ng-repeat="star in row.stars")
          i.star.yellow.icon
```